# PLAY: How to create hyperlinks in a javascript file that link to a controller method?

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am building a WebApp with Play Framework 2.2.1 and want to generate hyperlinks in my javascript file that links to a controller method. I have already created a jsRoutes object to make ajax requests:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Application.getData(id).ajax({...});
```

But what I now want is to save the url into a variable:

```
var url = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.test(par1, par2).url();
```

`.url()` doesn't work and I don't know what functions this object provides. Is there some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works without parenthesis at the end:

```
var url = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.test(par1, par2).url;
```

This way you get relative URL (path). You can also get HTTP method like this:

```
var method = jsRoutes.controllers.Application.test(par1, par2).method;
```

By the way, you can find out what functionality does an object support by using "console.log" function in Google Chrome:

```
console.log(jsRoutes.controllers.Application.test(par1, par2));
```

There I was able to see that "url" is not a function and therefore parenthesis are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought that I tried it already, but I was wrong. Do you know how one can create a link to files in the /public/... folder? routes.javascript.Assets.at() in Application.java and jsRoutes.Assets.at("") in JS doesn't work.